# Rest API aggregate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'd like rest  API from left aggregate using MongoDB, but not show any information. I'm using nosqlbooster for try my schema and it's working, but don't get pass infomation using middleware, someone can help me, any information that can one direction me.
Follow code:
**Model**

```js
 const userSchema = mongoose.Schema ({
      name: {
        type: String
      },
      email: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      },
      username: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      },
      course:[{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'course'}],
      password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      }
    });
    
     const courseSchema = new Schema({
       title: { type: String },
       createdBy: { type: String },
      createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now() }
    });
```

**Controller**

```
router.get('/getCourseUsers', passport.authenticate('jwt', {session:false}), (req, res)=>{
  const user =  User.aggregate([
    {
      $lookup:
        {
          from: "courses",
          localField: "course",
          foreignField: "_id",
          as: "user"
        }
   },
   {
       $unwind: "$course"
   }

]).cursor({})
.exec((users) => {
  console.log('users', users);
}, (err) => {
  console.log('err', err);
});    
})
```

I using nosqlbooster, the $lookup i got this information:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b38e3bc9dbf9113560a2d4c"),
    "email" : "marcos@marcos.com.br",
    "username" : "marcos",
    "course" : ObjectId("59ef4fcf941e450ccc132f13"),
    "password" : "$2a$10$ZwtV9drpSEF7y8swFsTM3..DCT80AFMib0EAnJgFXhJmgUR5.tHH.",
    "__v" : 0,
    "user" : {
        "course" : [
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("59ef4fcf941e450ccc132f13"),
                "title" : "Course Club ",
                "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-10-24T11:35:17.562-03:00"),
                "__v" : 0
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About cusors give erros for this don't working. I updated my mongoose and change some informations for this: `.then(function (users ) { res.json(users); console.log('users', users[0]); })`

Answer (score 0):

Your .exec callback method is not structured correctly. The callback usually has 2 parameters

```
.exec((err, data) => {})
```

Your code should therefore look like this.

```
router.get('/getCourseUsers', passport.authenticate('jwt', {session:false}), (req, res)=>{
  const user =  User.aggregate([
    {
      $lookup:
        {
          from: "courses",
          localField: "course",
          foreignField: "_id",
          as: "user"
        }
   },
   {
       $unwind: "$course"
   }

]).exec((err, users) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err)
    }
    console.log('users', users);    
  })
})
```

Comment: It may be the cursor method. Do you need you use cursors? I have updated my answer.